# List All Tables Modified in Last N Days

Tags: sql-server-2005

How to get the list of all tables modified in the last *N* days?

Comment: Modified - data or structure?

Answer (score 3):

If this is for data, you can use a query like:

```
exec sp_MSforeachtable 'SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS DatabaseName, last_user_update,*
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE database_id = DB_ID(''<yourDataBaseNameHere>'')
AND OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID(''?'')'
```

and filter the result for the date range you are interested in. See latt_user_updates column.

Comment: SELECT name
FROM sys.tables
WHERE DATEDIFF(D,modify_date, GETDATE()) < 60

Comment: finally i got the great solution. David Brabant thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to this answer too :

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/09/sql-server-find-last-date-time-updated-for-any-table/